# Delete duplicates sql across multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to delete duplicate data from a database where the data is across multiple tables.

I have 3 tables, Person, Person_Address_Map, and Address. I want to delete all the duplicate rows except one in my person table but I want to also check that the Address data is the same (but not delete any Rows in the Address table).

I have the following which deletes all but one duplicate entry in my Person table.

```
  DELETE
  FROM Person p
  WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 
    FROM Person temp
    Where p.name = temp.name AND
    p.id < temp.id);


 Person                    Person_Address_Map             Address
 | ID | Name | Age |       | Person_ID | Address_ID |     | ID | City | State |
 -------------------       --------------------------     ---------------------
 | 1  | Bob  |  20 |       |     1     |     1      |     | 1  | NYC  |  NY   | 
 | 2  | Bob  |  20 |       |     2     |     2      |     | 2  | NYC  |  NY   |
 | 3  | Jon  |  50 |       |     3     |     3      |     | 3  | LA   |  CA   | 
 | 4  | Jon  |  50 |       |     4     |     4      |     | 4  | SF   |  CA   |
```

Now for example my Address table has a city. The Person_Address_Map contains a Person ID and Address ID. How can I change this query so it doesn't just check that the 'name' of the Person is equal but also the 'city' in which they are mapped to in the Address table is equal? (without deleting any data from the Address table)

After deleting and leaving one duplicate I would expect the following left in my person table. With the Person_Address_Map also being updated.

```
 Person                    Person_Address_Map             Address
 | ID | Name | Age |       | Person_ID | Address_ID |     | ID | City | State |
 -------------------       --------------------------     ---------------------
 | 1  | Bob  |  20 |       |     1     |     1      |     | 1  | NYC  |  NY   | 
                                                          | 2  | NYC  |  NY   |
 | 3  | Jon  |  50 |       |     3     |     3      |     | 3  | LA   |  CA   | 
 | 4  | Jon  |  50 |       |     4     |     4      |     | 4  | SF   |  CA   |
```

Comment: You'd better show your table schema.

Comment: You're using both SQL server and Oracle?

Comment: So you want to delete the parent row (Person) but not the child row (Address) even though the child now be an orphan? Do you have referential integrity on these tables? Do you have cascading deletes on foreign keys? If not, what are you going to do with these newly created orphans? Most of this can be answered by providing ddl (including foreign keys and indexes) along with some sample data. sqlfiddle.com is a great place to start.

Comment: @SeanLange I have cascading delete for the Person and Person_Address_Map. I updated the question with more of what I am looking for.

Comment: Well this is nothing like seeing the actual table definitions. But what is question here. You said you have a query that already does what I understand your desired result to be.

Comment: @SeanLange My Query only checks the data in the Person table. I would also need to check that the City and State for each Person is the same. In the example Person with ID 3 and 4 will not be deleted since the City and State do not match

Comment: I don't think you fully understand the structure of the data you are trying to modify. You inherited these tables from a previous dev? For what I see, the Addresses are independent entities and address ID 1 and two are duplicates; that is step one. You also need to treat Persons ans entities and find a way to uniquely identify them. Person_address_map is a linking table between two independent entities. This is a problem of data structure and not 'Where is my T-SQL?'.

Comment: So add a couple joins to the subselect in your query so you return the Address information too. It seems like your data structures are the real problem here. You seem to have data is not well organized or normalized.

Comment: what would make you belive that just becasue the city and state are teh same that they are duplicated people? There are many John Smiths in NYC, NY who are definitely different people. Sometimes even people are at the same address with the same name (think father and son).

Comment: The first DELETE command is incorrect because of this : you are ASSUMING there is no different person with the same name. That is an extremely dangerous assumption, which is very likely to be false. Subsequently, you cannot remove records with computer code only.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this should work,

```
DELETE
  FROM PERSON P
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM (WITH TABLE_ AS (SELECT P.ID,
                                       P.NAME,
                                       P.AGE,
                                       PERSON_ID,
                                       ADDRESS_ID,
                                       A.ID ADD_ID,
                                       A.CITY,
                                       A.STATE
                                  FROM PERSON             P,
                                       PERSON_ADDRESS_MAP PA,
                                       ADDRESS_           A
                                 WHERE P.ID = PA.PERSON_ID
                                   AND PA.ADDRESS_ID = A.ID)
                 SELECT A1.ID, TABLE_.NAME
                   FROM ADDRESS_ A1, TABLE_
                  WHERE TABLE_.ADD_ID != A1.ID
                    AND TABLE_.CITY = A1.CITY
                    AND TABLE_.STATE = A1.STATE) DELETABLE_
                  WHERE P.ID > DELETABLE_.ID
                    AND P.NAME = DELETABLE_.NAME
        );
```

This is the table definitions I used,

```
CREATE TABLE person (
         ID         NUMBER(5),
         NAME       VARCHAR2(15) ,
         AGE        NUMBER(3));
CREATE TABLE Person_Address_Map (
         Person_ID          NUMBER(5),
         Address_ID          NUMBER(5)
         );         
CREATE TABLE Address_ (
         ID         NUMBER(5),
         City        VARCHAR2(15) ,
         State        VARCHAR2(15));         

INSERT INTO person VALUES (1,'Bob',20);         
INSERT INTO person VALUES (2,'Bob',20);
INSERT INTO person VALUES (3,'Jon',50);
INSERT INTO person VALUES (4,'Jon',50);

INSERT INTO Person_Address_Map VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO Person_Address_Map VALUES (2,2);
INSERT INTO Person_Address_Map VALUES (3,3);
INSERT INTO Person_Address_Map VALUES (4,4);

INSERT INTO Address_ VALUES (1,'NYC','NY');
INSERT INTO Address_ VALUES (2,'NYC','NY');
INSERT INTO Address_ VALUES (3,'LA','CA');
INSERT INTO Address_ VALUES (4,'CA','CA');
```

I did not check the cascade constraints.. I guess it should not give you any problems.